# vscode extention console.log doesn't work

Tags: javascript, debugging, vscode-extensions

Let me know if any information is missing instead of straight disliking my question.

I have created a vscode extension using "yo code" I have this example code:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {
    
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('replsync.run', function () {
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("test");

        console.log("test");
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

the thing is that when I try to run the command only the pop up is being shown but console.log doesn't appear any where. I am not sure if my package.json file is correct:

```
{
  "name": "replsync",
  "displayName": "ReplSync",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.72.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onCommand:replsync.run"
  ],
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [{
      "command": "replsync.run",
      "title": "run"
    }]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "node ./test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.72.0",
    "@types/glob": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/node": "16.x",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "glob": "^8.0.3",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you running the extension + where are you looking for the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I switched to typescript and it fixed probably it was because of my setup